# Add icon to legend text

Tags: highcharts

This is my chart:

```
$('#charsContentDiv').highcharts({
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'xy',
        height: 337
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    }, 
    xAxis: [{
        categories: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez']
    }],
    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Desempenho',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value}',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        }
    }, 
    {   // Secondary yAxis
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        labels: {
          enabled: false
        }
    }],
    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },
    legend: {
        title: {
            text: '<i class=\"fa fa-arrow-up\"></i><span> Direção: '+direction+ '</span>'
        },
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'top',
        x: 60,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Desempenho',
        type: 'column',
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        name: 'Meta',
        type: 'line',
        data: [80.0, 80.0, 80.0, 80.0, 80.0, 80.0, 80.0, 80.0, 80.0, 80.0, 80.0, 80.0]          
    }]
});
```

And this is how it is displayed
[image]

What I'm willing to do is add an image in the left side of "Direção". I tried it like this:

```
title: {
    text: '<img src=\"arrow.jpg\"></img> <span> Direção: '+direction+"</span>"
}
```

But only the text is displayed. Is there any way to add an image to the title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With SVG, just insert the code point instead of all the `<i class=\"fa fa-arrow-up\">` fanciness:

```
legend: {
    title: {
         text:'\uf062'+'Direção: '+direction
     },
}
```

You can see the unicode maps [here](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/), drop the html escape code `&#x` and replace with javascripts `\u`.

For this to work **do not** set useHTML to true.  You also have to set the font for your svg `text` elements to that of fontawesome font set:

svg text {
       font-family: FontAwesome;
   }

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/J8YQC/).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useHTML` option to use `html` in a text. Otherwise only few html tags will be supported.

So, this should work,

```
legend: {
    useHTML: true,
    title: {
        text: '<img src=\"arrow.jpg\"></img> <span> Direção: '+direction+ '</span>'
    },
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'top',
    x: 60,
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'
}
```

Comment: Tried and it didn't work (the image is not displayed). I took a look at [highcharts docs](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting#html) and it says that `The following tabs are supported: <b>, <strong>, <i>, <em>, <br/>, <span>`. Since I'm using Bootstrap with Font Awesome icons, I tried `text: '<i class=\"fa fa-arrow-up\"></i><span> Direção: '+direction+ '</span>'` and still no success. I'm gonna post my whole code so you could please tell me where am I missing here?

Comment: Here is the fiddle: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7T32E/). I don't know how to add icons neither images to jsfiddle, you can try it on your side and then I try it on my application

Comment: I searched docs and I don't think it's possible to add html in title. You can try something like this though [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7T32E/2/). `renderer.image` takes parameter as `(x,y,width, height)`