# How do I display an icon at a point on a line chart using d3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am creating a simple line chart using d3, ... but instead of the standard points along the path, I'd like to display a fon-awesome icon such as 'fa-arrow-up'.

I've tried the following ..

```
var setDirectionalPrediction = function(points){
  points.each(function(){
    var point = $(this);
    point.append('<image>');
    var image = point.children()[0];
    $(image).addClass('fa fa-long-arrow-up');
  });

}

setDirectionalPrediction($('#rd-d3-graph path.nv-point'));
```

To no avail, ... any ideas ?

Answer (score 3):

Under the hood, FontAwesome and libraries like it are just setting the CSS content of their `<i>` tag to a unicode character from their font family.

If you inspect an icon `::before` you'll see something like this:

```
.fa-camera-retro:before {
  content: "\f083";
}
```

In SVG this would be equal to:

```
<text>&#xf083</text>
```

Translating this into d3 then becomes:

```
<style>
  .symbol {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 16px;
   }
</style>

<script>
  var t = svg.append("g")
    .selectAll(".symbol")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "symbol")
    .html(function(d,i){
      return "&#xf083";
    })
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      return x(d.x);
    })
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
      return y(d.y);
    });
</script>
```

Here's a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24375702/16363) I gave about Highcharts.

See d3.js example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mf3Q0CK6tdxxQlYUDKLX?p=preview).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
var image = ;//image link
```

Give the link to your image above

```
point.append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", image)
    .attr("x", -12)
    .attr("y", -12)
    .attr("width", 24)
    .attr("height", 24)
    ;
```

Make sure you give it attributes : x/y, width/height

Comment: So wishin' this would have worked, ... it doesn't. though the mark-up looks right.

Comment: Sorry mate :( works for me, would have been able to try and solve if you had a JSfiddle we could work on but looks like @Mark above me, has solved the problem :)) have fun