# Adding image in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am newbie in java script and d3.js . I wanted to add images to corresponding points in the chart. I went through a lot of questions and articles, but I was not able to figure out that properly. The following is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}
.bar:hover {
  fill: brown;
}
.axis--x path {
  display: none;
}
.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}
.circle {
  fill: steelblue;
}
.axis--y path, .axis--y line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: none;
}
</style>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<script src="http://localhost/d3.js"></script>
<script>
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 80},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x= d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([0, width]);

    y = d3.scaleBand().range([height, 0]).padding(0.1);
var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
d3.tsv("http://localhost/data1.tsv", function(d) {
  d.frequency = +d.frequency;
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.frequency); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.letter)+30; })
    .curve(d3.curveStepAfter);

  x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);

  y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("letter");

  g.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);

});
</script>
```

This image is the output of the above code:

[image: This image is the output of the above code]

I want to add icons or tiny image in the lines as in the link below

This image shows how I want to add icons to my chart:

[image: This image shows how I want to add icons to my chart]

A question similar to mine is [How do I display an icon at a point on a line chart using d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29081399/how-do-i-display-an-icon-at-a-point-on-a-line-chart-using-d3-js) , but that is not working for me, and I want to add my custom icons too.

Comment: Have you tried the image tag? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image

Comment: The answer in the similar question shouldn't be an issue. Could you let us know how exactly are you trying the embed icons using that approach? Also, could you please add some data?

Comment: I am trying to add images stored in my system instead of the circles plotted in the above code.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking to add images for tooltip like this [example](https://bl.ocks.org/alandunning/cfb7dcd7951826b9eacd54f0647f48d3), replace circle by image by adding something like

```
focus.append('svg:image')
.attr({
  'xlink:href': 'test.png', 
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  width: 10,
  height: 10
});
```

If looking to add images as data points, look at this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/38744a17f9c0141bcd04) replacing dots by image as above code.

Comment: I have added the following code 

 g.append('image')
  .data(data)
  .attr("xlink:href", "http://localhost/whatsapp-logo.jpg")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.frequency); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.letter)+30; })
    .attr("width", 24)
    .attr("height", 24)

However only the first image in the first image  is displayed and the rest are not displayed. Why is that so?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but was able to solve it.

Initially, I had a basic point style like this

```
   svg
      .append("g")
      .selectAll("dot")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date) } )
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.value) } )
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")
```

and changed to this to have an image as a point

```
  svg
    .append('g')
    .selectAll('dot')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('svg:image')
    .attr('xlink:href', function (d) {
      return 'paht/to/image'
    })
    .attr('x', function (d) {
      return x(d.date);
    })
    .attr('y', function (d) {
      return y(d.value);
    });
```

If you want to see the whole context, my chart was based on this example https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/connectedscatter_basic.html